# Is there a way to find the location of rapid change in a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have several months of data stored in a pandas dataframe. For each month additional resources can be allocated and rapid increases occur in the data. I'm trying to find the point where the increase occurs (if it occurs) and drop all prior data.

Example df:

```py
data = [random.randint(1,10) if i < 15 else random.randint(70,80) for i in range(30)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['Jan']*len(data), 'data': data})
```

I'd like to find the point where it jumps from ~5 -> ~75 and get rid of previous data

if the series doesn't contain a sharp increase:

```py
data = [random.randint(70, 80) for _ in range(30)]
```

if should keep the entire month of data.

Comment: Its not very clear as to what do you mean by getting rid of the previous data but you can find the index of the sharp increase using (df['data']-df['data'].shift()).idxmax() and magnitude using (df['data']-df['data'].shift()).max()

Comment: I basically mean just taking the subset after that point. df.iloc[increase_idx:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution, by use `diff` and `idxmax`

```
n=70
s=df.groupby('month').data.diff()
df1=df[df.index>=(s>=n).groupby(df['month']).transform('idxmax')].copy()
```

Comment: Is there anyway to find it without defining n? The actual data can be all different ranges.

Comment: Use percentile instead of a static value @EvanBrittain. For example, rather than filtering above a fixed threshold value, use something like the value at 90th percentile. This would vary with data, the prior wouldn't.

Comment: @EvanBrittain how about use pdct_change